# Nodemailer pug iterate array with each

Tags: pug, nodemailer

I'm using [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) with `pug` templates for sending emails from my app. I'm encountering an issue with the iteration over an array.

I have the following code

```
p Hello #{name},
br
ul
    each val in #{description}
         li= val
```

Where `description` is an standard array sent from my node controller `['test','test2']`

I've tried to declare a variable and did not have any results in any way.

Can someone please help me with this and show me how is the proper way to iterate through that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the `each` iterator. The `#{}` expression is used for concatenating variables inside text blocks. For a each iteration you just write the variable name without the `#{}`.

```
p Hello #{name},
br
ul
    each val in description
         li= val
```

You can check the Pugjs reference [here](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)

Comment: I've tried even like that in the first place. But I get the same `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error

Comment: The error was another variable that overwritten the `description`, the iteration was fine... Thanks